# Play 2.0/Java - Is there a way to get the validation done post request data binding?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

In play 2.0 you can get the request binding with validation done (via annotations) by :

```
ABCForm abcForm=(ABCForm)form(ABCForm.class).bindFromRequest().get();
```

The problem I have is , I want to get the validation done after trimming the form values.
So is there a way to either defer or call the validation stuff post binding in play 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding and validation are combined. So validation after the binding is not possible, as far as I know. However you can create a `validate()` method, in which you trim your values before validating them. For example:

```
public class User {

    public String name;

    public String validate() {
        name.trim
        if(name == "") {
            return "Name is required";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `validate()` method will be invoked when you bind a form. So you can make sure your data is valid, but errors won't be automatically added to the `Form.Field` objects. So it is certainly a nice solution.

There are also pretty much discussions about Form validation in Play's Google Group, so if you want to know more about the binding/validation problems I recommend reading them: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/%5B2.0%5D$20validation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/%5B2.0%5D%2420validation).

Comment: Li-o, thanks for your reply, I am aware of the validate(),which will be always called during the binding process, what i was actually looking at was to re-use the annotation based validation logic, instead of writing it once more...

Comment: Found this thread on the group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/GyNQFJNat4A/discussion. Keeping in mind that Guillaume is a core developer of Play2.0, I think his answer is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Li-o, thanks for your reply. I will look into that. I will close this question. Thank u..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify your values before validation. You can create a setter for your field and do your trims there.